# How to make Python packages in a Artifact Registry available to Vertex AI Custom Jobs?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-vpn

I started working with Vertex AI and tried to create a custom job.
The `requirements.txt` file contains:

```
--extra-index-url https://europe-west4-python.pkg.dev/.../europe-west4-python/simple
my_package1==1.2.3
my_package2=4.5.6
```

In the build log I get the following output:

```
Step #1 - "create job": Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com, https://europe-west4-python.pkg.dev/.../europe-west4-python/simple
Step #1 - "create job": WARNING: Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable on attempt 1 of 3. Reason: timed out
Step #1 - "create job": WARNING: Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable on attempt 2 of 3. Reason: timed out
Step #1 - "create job": WARNING: Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable on attempt 3 of 3. Reason: timed out
Step #1 - "create job": WARNING: Authentication failed using Compute Engine authentication due to unavailable metadata server.
Step #1 - "create job": WARNING: Failed to retrieve Application Default Credentials: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
Step #1 - "create job": WARNING: Trying to retrieve credentials from gcloud...
Step #1 - "create job": WARNING: Could not open the configuration file: [/home/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default].
Step #1 - "create job": ERROR: (gcloud.config.config-helper) You do not currently have an active account selected.
Step #1 - "create job": Please run:
Step #1 - "create job": 
Step #1 - "create job":   $ gcloud auth login
Step #1 - "create job": 
Step #1 - "create job": to obtain new credentials.
Step #1 - "create job": 
Step #1 - "create job": If you have already logged in with a different account:
Step #1 - "create job": 
Step #1 - "create job":     $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT
Step #1 - "create job": 
Step #1 - "create job": to select an already authenticated account to use.
Step #1 - "create job": WARNING: Failed to retrieve credentials from gcloud: gcloud command exited with status: Command '['gcloud', 'config', 'config-helper', '--format=json(credential)']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Step #1 - "create job": WARNING: Artifact Registry PyPI Keyring: No credentials could be found.
Step #1 - "create job": WARNING: Keyring is skipped due to an exception: Failed to find credentials, Please run: `gcloud auth application-default login or export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path/to/service/account/key>`
Step #1 - "create job": User for europe-west4-python.pkg.dev: ERROR: Exception:
Step #1 - "create job": Traceback (most recent call last):
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
Step #1 - "create job":     status = run_func(*args)
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
Step #1 - "create job":     return func(self, options, args)
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 400, in run
Step #1 - "create job":     requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
Step #1 - "create job":     result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
Step #1 - "create job":     state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 348, in resolve
Step #1 - "create job":     self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
Step #1 - "create job":     if not criterion.candidates:
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
Step #1 - "create job":     return bool(self._sequence)
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
Step #1 - "create job":     return any(self)
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
Step #1 - "create job":     return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 44, in _iter_built
Step #1 - "create job":     for version, func in infos:
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 279, in iter_index_candidate_infos
Step #1 - "create job":     result = self._finder.find_best_candidate(
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 889, in find_best_candidate
Step #1 - "create job":     candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 830, in find_all_candidates
Step #1 - "create job":     page_candidates = list(page_candidates_it)
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index/sources.py", line 134, in page_candidates
Step #1 - "create job":     yield from self._candidates_from_page(self._link)
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 790, in process_project_url
Step #1 - "create job":     index_response = self._link_collector.fetch_response(project_url)
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 461, in fetch_response
Step #1 - "create job":     return _get_index_content(location, session=self.session)
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 364, in _get_index_content
Step #1 - "create job":     resp = _get_simple_response(url, session=session)
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 135, in _get_simple_response
Step #1 - "create job":     resp = session.get(
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 600, in get
Step #1 - "create job":     return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 518, in request
Step #1 - "create job":     return super().request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
Step #1 - "create job":     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 708, in send
Step #1 - "create job":     r = dispatch_hook("response", hooks, r, **kwargs)
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/hooks.py", line 30, in dispatch_hook
Step #1 - "create job":     _hook_data = hook(hook_data, **kwargs)
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/auth.py", line 270, in handle_401
Step #1 - "create job":     username, password, save = self._prompt_for_password(parsed.netloc)
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/auth.py", line 233, in _prompt_for_password
Step #1 - "create job":     username = ask_input(f"User for {netloc}: ")
Step #1 - "create job":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 204, in ask_input
Step #1 - "create job":     return input(message)
Step #1 - "create job": EOFError: EOF when reading a line
Step #1 - "create job": The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r ./requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 2
Step #1 - "create job": ERROR: (gcloud.ai.custom-jobs.create) 
Step #1 - "create job": Docker failed with error code 2.
Step #1 - "create job": Command: docker build --no-cache -t gcr.io/.../cloudai-autogenerated/...:20221212.14.42.28.274055 --rm -f- .
Step #1 - "create job":
```

The package `keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth` is installed.

`service-...@gcp-sa-aiplatform-cc.iam.gserviceaccount.com` and my service account specified in the build trigger have access rights to read from the artifact registry. The same I tried locally and also have the same problem from my PC.

My first understanding was that the Vertex AI containers do not have a network connection, but at least the Google homepage I can access.
However, `metadata.google.internal` times out.

I tried to add `network = "default"` and `network = "cloudbuild"` (read both) to my °config.yaml` file creating the custom job, but still get the error.

Further I added some output via `RUN` and `ONBUILD RUN` to the `Dockerfile` of my base image and can see that the first has the project and service account from the build trigger set, but the `docker build` done by `gcloud ai custom-jobs create` does not have it any more.

Is there another way than hard-coding an access key for a service account into the base image?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use `Vertex AI` but usually in `GCP`, if you want using `Python` packages from `Artifact Registry`, there are 2 [methods](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/authentication) (the documentation is complete and give the different steps).

- Keyring (more recommended)
- Authentication with token key

At the end you will generate a `pip.conf` file contaning the `extra index url` targeting on the url to `Artifact` registry.

If you use the method with token key as `base64`, the following command will generate the `pip.conf` file for you :

```bash
gcloud artifacts print-settings python --project=PROJECT \
    --repository=REPOSITORY \
    --location=LOCATION --json-key=KEY-FILE
```

In this case, you have to follow the best practice for a `Json` key.

In all the cases, at the end you have to copy the `pip.conf` file in the expected place, to give to `Vertex AI` the possibility to download packages from `Artifact Registry`.

Comment: Sorry that I did not mention that `keyring` is already installed, based on the explanation of the link you mentioned.
To my understanding case 1b of https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/authentication#search-order should have applied: "Credentials that the default service account for Compute Engine, Google Kubernetes Engine, Cloud Run, App Engine, or Cloud Functions provides.".
The service account used for the trigger has the rights to read from the artifact registry.
But thanks, I will try having the key for the service account in the container.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you will solve your issue.